# keep numbering after sorting divs

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs which is sorted in two groups. Each div is  numbered 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0... etc. with a class="container-x".

After sorting the divs have changed position, but I would like them to still keep this numbering.

How do I update their class name after sorting?

Markyp:

```
<div class="container container-1">
    <div class="terminal" data-price="195">
        <h3>195</h3>
    </div>
    I should come in 2nd in group 1 which is displayed first.
</div>

<div class="container container-2">
    <div class="terminal" data-price="220">
        <h3>220</h3>
    </div>
    I should come in 3rd in group 1 which is displayed first.
</div>

<div class="container container-0">
    <div class="terminal" data-price="740">
        <h3>740</h3>
    </div>
    I should come in 2nd in group 2 which is displayed last.
    <div class="anotherGroup">Group 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container container-1">
    <div class="terminal" data-price="140">
        <h3>140</h3>
    </div>
    I should come in 1st in group 2 which is displayed last.
    <div class="anotherGroup">Group 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container container-2">
    <div class="terminal" data-price="130">
        <h3>130</h3>
    </div>
    I should come in 1st in group 1 which is displayed first.
</div>
```

Script:

```
var _count = 0;

$('.terminal').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('price') - $(b).data('price');
}).map(function () {
    return $(this).closest('.container');
}).each(paint);

function paint(_, container) {
    if ($(container).children('.anotherGroup')[0]) {
        $(container).parent().append(container);
    } 
    else {
        var next = paint.next;
        if (next) {
            $(container).insertAfter(next);
        } 
        else {
            $(container).parent().prepend(container);
        }
            paint.next = container;
        }
    };
```

I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TavH/8/).

Comment: I've said it before, I'll say it again, don't use incremental `id` or `class` attributes. It leads to maintenance problems, especially when the content is dynamically amended.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan. If you want to keep the classes for styling then consider switching to using the `:nth-child` selector: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to update the class numbering:

```
$('.container').each(function (i, v) {
    $(this).attr('class', 'container container-' + i);
});
```

But I as well agree with as Rory McCrossan's comment, it is not a good practice to use use incremental id or class attributes.

For instance, if you're only using the incremental class name for selection purposes, jQuery's [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) might come in handy for you:

```
// this will select the second 'container' div
var $div = $('.container:eq(1)');
```